# cakephp session timeout not working

Tags: session, cakephp, timeout

I have cakephp site, I was having problem that was after being idle for about >= 1 hour it gets log-out automatically
so I googled to extend timeout for that I wrote the following in `core.php`

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout'  => 28800,  // 8 hours.
        )
    );
```

I want to keep a logged in user logged-in even after being idle for less than 8hours
but this is not working
how can I sort out this?

Comment: You can use cookie to save and retrieve the user's detail

Answer (score 1):

According to CakePHP manual, the unit of Session.timeout option is "minute", so 8 hours should be 60*8=480

Regarding the setting not work, I think maybe you could try to clean the cakePHP cache files / restart web server or change the debug level to 2 for troubleshooting?

[CakePHP 2.0 manual sessions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html)

Comment: I did this but still logging me out after about 30min

Comment: Have you check you php.ini session.gc-maxlifetime paramter? if you are using default php session, I was wondering to know if cakephp can overwrite the php.ini setting.

the default value of php to clean up session files is 1440 second, around 24 minutes. 

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using CakePHP 3, that is why you are facing this issue. Session timeout does not work in CakePHP 3, You might use cookie_lifetime, please check https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5664

Comment: Might improve your answer by guiding OP on `cookie_lifetime` use.

Comment: This will increase the cookies expire time not the session timeout time...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in CakePHP 1.3

The problem was that CakePHP was using the settings defined in php.ini instead of the one I was defining in core.php

So I had to change in core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');
```

to

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake');
```

And it worked like a charm!